# SharePoint Redirect By Active Directory Group

Tags: sharepoint-2013, web-parts

i want to redirect an user by an ad group. I thought i just use HttpContext.Current.User.User.IsInRole() to check if a user is in a ad group.
Anyway this method always returns false.

At the moment iam really not sure how to fullfill my approach.

Thanks for help.

BR,
Tomson

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup on SPWeb? Have a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.iscurrentusermemberofgroup%28v=office.14%29.aspx)